# Video streaming in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, video, nginx, passenger, jplayer

I am not sure if this is a programming question or a web server config question.

The video files are not in `public/` so requests have to go through a controller.

In my controller:

```
  def play_video
   video=Video.find params[:id]
   response.headers['Content-Length'] = File.size(video.path).to_s
   send_data File.read(video.path,mode: 'rb'), type: video.mime_type, disposition: 'inline'
```

end

On the client-side I am using `JPlayer` for now.In Firefox running on Linux in both development and production it works properly, I can jump forward or backward without issue. In just about every other browser on Linux and Windows, it plays properly, but that is it, no skipping forward or backwards, in development and production. I would put it up to a `JPlayer` bug but I get the exact same behavior with using just `<video> with control attribute`, as well as `mediaelement.js`.

In development I am using `Thin`, on production `Passenger` and `Nginx`.

nginx.conf:

```
    worker_processes  4;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
     sendfile        on;
     #tcp_nopush     on;
  http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;
    keepalive_timeout  120;
   gzip  on;
   server {
        server_tokens off;
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /path/to/public;  
        passenger_enabled on;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;  includeSubdomains;";       
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        include mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        #removed SSL config stuff
        ...
```

I am not sure where the problem lies. I get no error messages when trying to skip forward.

Please don't link to Rails HTTP Streaming tutorials as they are all lame and not-at-all-helpful send "hello world" to the client 10 times examples, unless you have one that actually addresses video streaming. Anything I did find were for old versions of rails and other web servers.

Answer (score 2):

This is an anti pattern what you are trying to do, send_file is fully blocking synchronical mechanism, basically it requires N number of Rails processes as many requests as your app will serve at a time. It is being done by a reason to have controlled access to file or perform any kind of pre/post processing: permission check, audit etc.

If this is the anti pattern how the pattern looks like:
1) X-Accel-Redirect
2) Async permission check via auth_request module

In the first case your Rails app returns back only the file's URL within the X-Accel-Redirect header with empty body followed by closing this request so Rails can continue serving a new request again immediately not waiting until a client gets the file (in case of slow client's connection Rails can't free process up until it finished). Basically to serve 10 large video files simultaneously 10 workers require you to have. X-Accel-Redirect makes same job with only one worker:

**Rails**

```
def download
  video=Video.find params[:id]
  headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "#{video.file_name}"
  render nothing: true
end
```

**Nginx**

```
location /video {
  internal;
  root /mnt/video;
}
```

The alternative is [auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) which is similar by efficiency but you need to know file target URL beforehand not generate by server. Auth_request location is internal and it handles authentication by Rails route followed by rejection or pass user to target video file URL:

**Nginx**

```
location /video/ {
    root /mnt/video;
    auth_request /auth;
    ...
}

location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am getting nothing but 404's so I want to verify a few things if you could be so kind. config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' needs to be uncommented? location /video where video is the controller name? mime-type and file size don't need to be passed?

Comment: I guess this configuration (Rails 3+) turns send_file into what Nginx actually does, so choose this option and feel free to use send_file. Yes, location /video is a sample, you can choose your option path. Mine type Nginx sets by itself based on file extension.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying, keep my controller as is and add location directive to nginx?

Comment: Almost. Change send_data to send_file, uncomment config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header and use Nginx location

Comment: I did that, and I am getting the same behavior across browser(which is probably a jplayer issue), although it seems as if memory usage is lower. Do I need to use the x_sendfile_header line in the controller?